# Error: angularjs : js file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova

this  my  js file  i dont know  why it does not  work, i want  to execute  cordova  cmd from  js file:when i click in the button  the project wil be create:

```
(function(angular) {
 'use strict';
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
  myApp.factory("items", function() {
  var items = {};
   items.data = [];
   return items;
    });
  myApp.controller("createController", function createController($scope,    items) {
$scope.items = items;

$scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
  items.data.splice(index, 1);
}
$scope.addItem = function(index) {
  items.data.push({
    id: $scope.items.data.length + 1,
    title: $scope.newName
  });
      $scope.newItemName=""
      $scope.idname=""

   var name=$scope.newName;
   var id=$scope.idname;
   var fs = require('fs');
   var path = require('path');
   var sys = require('sys');
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
     sys.puts(stdout);
     }
     exec("cordova create"+name+id, puts);
    }
     });
      })(angular)
```

Comment: Angular is a front-end library. You can't launch a JS file like this. You have to create your own angular's project with html/js, ...

Comment: I create my  own project: index.html and test.js.

Comment: Then if all is fine. You just have to open index.html

Comment: i have this error in the console:util.puts: Use console.log instead util.js:85deprecated util.js:85(anonymous function) util.js:69puts te.js:34exithandler child_process.js:735EventEmitter.emit events.js:107maybeClose child_process.js:991ChildProcess._handle.onexit

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.x cannot be run backend (like with Node), it only works when running in an actual browser on an actual html-page. Running a single js file with Angular does not make sense.

I.e. you need to create an index.html, include your angular.js file (from a cdn or from local) in head or body and then include your test.js. Note that since test depends on Angular you **must** include Angular first. Then, simply open index.html